# Why am I getting table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it error?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have such simple trigger. I have no compilation error.

```
CREATE OR replace TRIGGER test_triger
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON users
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    varii NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT Count(dur.id)
    INTO   varii
    FROM   users dur
    WHERE  dur.id = :old.id
            OR dur.id = :new.id;

    IF( varii > 0 ) THEN
      Raise_application_error(-20001, 'error!, ');
    END IF;
END;
```

When I invoke update  I have such error:

```
TEST.USERS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it.
```

what does it mean?

ORA-04091, ORA-06512 and ORA-04088 Errors.

Comment: You're selecting from the same table that you're updating.

Comment: @Sathya
BEFORE update, I want to see if everything is well. If everything is not ok I throw error. why this is problem? Cant I do that? and solution?

Comment: what do you mean by 'everything is well'? Why do you need to test? What do you want to test?

Comment: I have graph of   user roles. when administrator updates roles, he/she should not manage to make loop. For this I wrote trigger. BEFORE UPDATE I check if there will be loop, if admin execute update command. Is not everything clear?